# WinForms: How can I use a timer to run code at the end of it's interval but have the interval reset through it's countdown

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, timer

I am trying to output a log to the form, but I want this clearing after 5 seconds of visibility. But if I output another log during this 5 second countdown, I wish to reset it back up to 5 seconds.

I.e.

OutputLog("message", "title");
5..4..3..2..1..
ClearLog();

But I may have the case of this;

OutputLog("message", "title");
5..4..
OutputLog("message2", "title2");
5..4..3..2..
OutputLog("message3", "title3");
5..4..3..2..1..
ClearLog();

All meanwhile not halting the current thread.

Currently I have the below, but this is a constant 5 seconds, so a log may only appear for 0.5 seconds for example;

```
Task.Run(async delegate
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    lblLogOutput.Text = "";
});
```

Comment: Just use a Timer with an Interval of 5000.  In OutputLog stop and start the timer.  When it ticks then you know that 5 seconds have passed.

Comment: I will check this out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Stop` function followed immediately by the Start function to "restart" the timer.

```
private void restartTimer() 
{
  timer1.Stop();
  timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: You should probably mention _what_ type of _"timer"_ you are talking about.  Currently, OP isn't uising one